# Why Jack was carrying the wooden sword

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, curse-of-the-black-pearl

Just after saving the Elizabeth, Norrington get Jack Sparrow captured by his man. When they search him, Norrington sarcastically points out that he is carrying a useless compass which does not point to north and a wooden sword.

Later, it was explained later that the compass has the magical property that it points to whatever the owner desires most.

However, is it ever explained in any of the movies in the series why he had a wooden sword?

Answer (score 9):

### He wasn't

As we can see in the video below, right after he checks the compass, he inspects Jack's sword and say:

> And I half expected it to be made of wood.

As we clearly see, by how the sword looks and the sound that it makes when Norrington inspects it, **It's not made of wood**.

Also he uses his sword later when fighting against Will.

Answer (score 1):

### It wasn't necessary to explain..

It was just sarcasm, despite being possessor of useless compass, (which doesn't point north as purpose of being a compass).

Norrington sarcastically implied that he was expected that Jack might be using a wooden sword rather than using actual sword. Just because every other item Jack had 
*(Compass that doesn't point north, gun with no additional powder and wasn't used to shot in long time etc.. )* 
was useless as Norrington saw it.

Answer (score 0):

Norrington "and I half expected it to be a wooden sword".....It was a real sword

Comment: I believe it was, "And I half expected it to be made of wood."